# flask how to use python built in function in html template (Jinja 2)

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Hi so I'm decrypting information so the value return is coming back as a byte. I'm trying to print it as a str so I can get rid of the b'' format. But I can't figure out how to do it in html template

```
{% for row in rows %}
{{ repr(password.decrypt(row['text']))[2:-1] }}

{% endfor %}
```

This is the code I tried, but I get repr not define. I'm trying to use python built in function repr in my html file

Comment: Why not perform this operation on your iterable on the server-side instead of doing it in the template?

Comment: I can't, because the server side is sending it as a massive json file. I mean I can but it gets really complicated

Comment: template should be used only to display result which you should calculate in Python/flask code.

Comment: thanks I'll figure something out

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for row in rows %}
    {{ password.decrypt(row['text'])[2:-1]|string }}    
{% endfor %}
```

and pass the `decrypt()` function by `retrun render_template("index.html", decrypt=decrypt)` into your jinja template.

However, the `jinja` template will still go through your `flask route` to render as a `real html` before sending it to frontend. So I don't think there is difficulty in moving the function into `py` file.

Comment: thanks but the decrypt was not the problem. It was repr. However, I found a way to do it on the server side

Comment: @dragonn Yeah, that why I wrote `{{ password.decrypt(row['text'])[2:-1]|string }}` there for you to solve your problem, but glad to hear that you solved it.